# Почему не работают политики учетных записей в АД?

Tags: windows, centos, samba, active-directory

Скриншоты не хотят вставляться. тут подробнее [ссылка](https://toster.ru/q/262418)
Однако, при попытке изменить пароль на "0000" Появляется ошибка, мол не соответствуют политики.
папка sysvol доступна. никакие политики не срабатывают. помогите.
Сервер на Centos 6.5 sernet samba ad 4.1
В чем причина?

Comment: DefaultDomainPolicy совсем выключить в AD нельзя, а там довольно жесткие требования к паролю

Answer (score 1):

из ответов по ссылке:

---

На четвёртой Самбе политики паролей задаются через командную строку:

```
$ samba-tool domain passwordsettings set
```

Список возможных параметров после `set`:

```
--quiet -выход
--complexity=on|off|default - Пароль должен отвечать требованиям сложности
--store-plaintext=on|off|default - Хранить пароли используя обратимое шифрование
--history-length=число - Число хранимых предыдущих паролей пользователей(Требовать неповторяемость паролей)
--min-pwd-length=число - Минимальное количество символов в пароле
--min-pwd-age=число - Минимальный срок действия пароля
--max-pwd-age=число - Максимальный срок действия пароля
```